# Valgrind reports invalid read size of 1 while using strncpy in function

Tags: c, string, memory, strncpy

I am getting the following error while using strncpy:

```
Invalid read of size 1
==11703==    at 0x4C2D791: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (vg_replace_strmem.c:555)
==11703==    by 0x400BD6: searchGNode
```

This is the funciton searchGNode. I've read other stackoverflow posts which say to null terminate the strings you use strncpy on however, I still get the error. I've tried doing this both and before after the use of strncpy and it doesnt seem to work. What could be the problem?

```
 41 GNode * searchGNode ( GNode * root, GNode * newnode, int * flag,int k,GNode * last)
 42 {
 43   GNode * found = NULL;
 44   char rootstr[MAX_KMER_LEN];
 45   char newstr[MAX_KMER_LEN];
 46   if (root == NULL)
 47   {
 48     return found;
 49   }
 50   //rootstr[k] = '\0';
 51   //newstr[k] = '\0';
 52   strncpy(rootstr,root->key,k); // copy the root's key into here
 53   strncpy(newstr,newnode->key,k); // copy the newnode's key iinto here
 54   /*if (root == NULL)
 55   {
 56     return found; // returning null
 57   }*/
 58   rootstr[k] = '\0';
 59   newstr[k] = '\0';
 60   if ( strcmp(rootstr,newstr) == 0)
 61   {
 62     return root; // this is the match , we have found that this node exists in the graph
 63   }
 64   found = searchGNode(root->one,newnode,flag,k,last); // search first pointer
 65   if (found != NULL)
 66   {
 67     *flag = 1;
 68     insertGNode(last,found); // insert if we find
 69     return found;
 70   }
 71   found = searchGNode(root->two,newnode,flag,k,last);
 72   if (found != NULL)
 73   {
 74     *flag = 1;
 75     insertGNode(last,found);
 76     return found;
 77   }
 78   found = searchGNode(root->three,newnode,flag,k,last);
 79   if (found != NULL)
 80   {
 81     *flag = 1;
 82     insertGNode(last,found);
 83     return found;
 84   }
  85   found = searchGNode(root->four,newnode,flag,k,last);
 86   if (found != NULL)
 87   {
 88     *flag = 1;
 89     insertGNode(last,found);
 90     return found;
 91   }
 92   return newnode;
 93 }
```

I've also tried strcpy, and I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your variable `root` points to an object?  Certainly, it isn't NULL because you check for that but it could be pointing to uninitialized memory.

Comment: Depending on whether `k` is the size of the buffer or one less, the statements like `rootstr[k] = '\0';` my be incorrect and index beyond bounds.

Comment: @Weather Vane MAX_KMER_LEN is  16, and k is not. Is that the error? Should I be doing rootstr[15] = '\0' instead?

Comment: Also @Jerry Jeremiah, I have verified that what it points is not NULL by printing before I put it into the function

Comment: I didn't notice that: you should be passing `MAX_KMER_LEN` to `strncpy` and terminating with `rootstr[MAX_KMER_LEN-1] = '\0';`. Don't hard code `15` or `16` if the size is already defined. If the source string is unterminated, you have *undefined behaviour* anyway - that is not what is (specifically) limited by `strncpy()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane should i be doing it after or before I use the strncpy function?

Comment: After, of course.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have tried the above, and I still get the same error. what else do you think could be happening?

Comment: Why are you using `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`? If you want to limit the size of strings, you should limit it in the source as well, not just when copying.

Comment: @Barmar I have done that as mentioned in the post and now I get more errors with unintialized values and conditional jumps. As well as the same invalid read size of 1.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that the source pointer is not initialized.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, but I have double checked that I intialized all the fields in the struct when I create it, before passing it in to these functions.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting earlier that using strcpy would fix this problem. But almost always using strncpy is a band-aid for some other problem in your code, it's rarely the correct solution.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and put breakpoints before all the `strncpy` calls, then check the values of the variables.